# Word for politicians truth, really a lie

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What is the word for something that is said but isnt true, but because it is said it is believed (by the masses) to be true and is never then undone easily? Often used by point scoring, or wriggling, politicians

Comment: Campaign pledge? ;-) Some of the politicians claim it is called a "white lie", but that is a matter of perspective I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think *[propaganda](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/propaganda)* is close to what you are looking for:

> - Information, especially of a biased or misleading nature, used to promote a political cause or point of view.  (ODO).

- The miners were no angels but the media was blatantly and cynically used as a propaganda machine for the government.
- The party’s leaders believed that a period of  propaganda would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would call these **invented myths, obfuscations,** or **fake promises,** depending on the exact situation. Sometimes they do at least rise to the level of **half-truths.**

Comment: John Howard in Australia referred to core and non-core promises. The latter can be broken with impunity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word you need is ***misconception***, often used for a widely held belief which isn't in fact true.

On a political level I suppose you could say that some people are in the business of ***planting or promulgating misconceptions***.

Answer (score 0):

**A politician's *'stock in trade'* is the peddling of seductive "half-truths"**

A half-truth is a deceptive statement that includes some element of truth. The statement might be partly true, the statement may be totally true but only part of the whole truth, or it may utilize some deceptive element, such as improper punctuation, or double meaning, especially if the intent is to deceive, evade, blame or misrepresent the truth.

> In his 1990 work *The Magic Lantern*: The Revolution of 1989 Witnessed in Warsaw, Budapest, Berlin, and Prague, Timothy Garton Ash responded to Václav Havel's call for "living in truth":
>
> “ Now we expect many things of politicians in a well-functioning parliamentary democracy. But "living in truth" is not one of them. ***In fact the essence of democratic politics might rather be described as "working in half-truth***."
> A Parliamentary democracy is, at its heart, a system of limited adversarial *mendacity*, in which each party attempts to present part of the truth as if it were the whole.

[**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-truth)

> **HALF-TRUTH**:
>
> **1**) a statement that is only partially true.
>
> **2**) a statement that mingles truth and falsehood with deliberate intent to deceive.
>
> [**Merriam‑Webster Dictionary** *online*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half-truth)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (not restricted to politicians) might be [factoid](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/factoid):

> An item of unreliable information that is reported and repeated so often that it becomes accepted as fact:
>
> *he addresses the facts and factoids which have buttressed the film’s legend*

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it **dirty politics**, **hoodwinking**, **bluff**, **ad hominem** - take your pick.